# Looping in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, csv, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am using python to loop a list of "keys" inside a knows url and extracting as an output. To do this I define a `get_urls(key)` function and then loops trough `key`. You can see my example code here:

```
import urllib3
import requests
urllib3.disable_warnings()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def get_urls(key):
    url = f'https://aurl.com/{key}#ltr-{key}'
    r = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        z=print(a['href'])
    return z
```

---

```
key = ['C','B']

urllist = []
for key in key:
    urllist.append(get_urls(key))

dflinks = pd.DataFrame(urllist) 
path = 'D://mycsv.csv'
dflinks.to_csv(path,index=False)
```

The first part of the code seems to be doing the job, as I see the desired urls in the `out`. However, I must have an error when saving these urls to a csv, as when I open the desired file it turns out to be empty.

I know I must be incurring in a very basic mistake here, I am learning python and would really appreciate your feedback. I am sure you will spot it fast :)

**Edit: something else that does not work:**

Another strategy that does no work is to substitute the line above the code for:

```
linklist = []
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        z=linklist.append(a['href'])
    return z
```

Comment: I noticed you have written `z=print(a['href'])` - try writing just `z=a['href']`. Also, this will return only the first link found which might not be what you want. Add `print(urllist)` instead to make sure you're getting the list you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks, @Taxel! yeah indeed with you option I am only getting the first element of each key, but print(urllist) does not really fix that, no? I would like the full list of urls for boths keys.

Comment: In the latter code, take off the `z=` and return `linklist` instead of `z`. Also, make sure you keep the indentation correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning what you want:

```
z = linklist.append(a['href'])
```

`.append()` returns `None`. It is a void function that you call to append a value in a list.
Also, you are returning `z`. Try returning the `linklist` that you created:

```
linklist = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    linklist.append(a['href'])
return linklist
```

You can also try a more pythonic code, but that is optional:

```
return [ a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) ]
```